# dateutil rruleset: How to combine EXRULE and RDATE correctly?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a `rruleset` with a daily recurrence rule and now I am trying to combine an RDATE with an EXRULE.

```
from dateutil.rrule import rruleset, rrule, DAILY, FR

rules = rruleset()
daily = rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 12))
rules.rrule(daily)
not_on_friday = rrule(freq=DAILY, byweekday=FR, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 12))
but_on_friday_21th = datetime(2022, 10, 21)
rules.exrule(not_on_friday)
rules.rdate(but_on_friday_21th)
rules.between(datetime(2022,10,12), datetime(2022,10,24))

>>
[datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 13, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 15, 0, 0), # the 14th is excluded as expected
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 22, 0, 0), # but the 21th is also excluded
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 23, 0, 0)]
```

Now, confusingly, when I combine my EXRULE with an EXDATE it works:

```
rules = rruleset()
daily = rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 12))
rules.rrule(daily)
not_on_friday = rrule(freq=DAILY, byweekday=FR, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 12))
but_also_not_on_the_22th_a_saturday = datetime(2022, 10, 22)
rules.exrule(not_on_friday)
rules.exdate(but_also_not_on_the_22th_a_saturday)
rules.between(datetime(2022,10,12), datetime(2022,10,24))

>>
[datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 15, 0, 0), # the 14th still excluded
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), # the 22th also excluded as expected
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 23, 0, 0)]
```

So, if possible at all, how to combine RDATE and EXRULE in my `rruleset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74054970/467366) you note that `exrule` is applied last, after all other inclusive rules which [actually does appear to be in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1). However, at least in `dateutil`, you can use an `rruleset` as the argument to `exrule`, so to accomplish what you want, you can try filtering out the date that you want *included* from the rule that gets passed to `exrule`, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rruleset, rrule, DAILY, WEEKLY, FR

# Create an rruleset that defaults to every day
rules = rruleset()
daily = rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 12))
rules.rrule(daily)

# Create an rruleset corresponding to the days we want to *exclude*: every
# Friday, except 2022-10-21
ex_set = rruleset()
ex_set.rrule(rrule(freq=WEEKLY, byweekday=FR, dtstart=datetime(2022, 10, 14)))
ex_set.exdate(datetime(2022, 10, 21))

# Use our second rule set as an exrule
rules.exrule(ex_set)

rules.between(datetime(2022,10,12), datetime(2022,10,24))
```

Since the date you want to *include* never appears in the `exrule`, it is not filtered out:

```
>>> print("\n".join(map(str,
...                     map(datetime.date,
...                         rules.between(datetime(2022, 10, 12),
...                                       datetime(2022, 10, 24))))))
2022-10-13
2022-10-15
2022-10-16
2022-10-17
2022-10-18
2022-10-19
2022-10-20
2022-10-21
2022-10-22
2022-10-23
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Combining `rrulesets` that way did not ever cross my mind.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently there is no such thing as an `EXRULE` in the iCalendar specs. Its just `RRULE`s. And `dateutils` `exdate` function states in the doc string:

```
def exrule(self, exrule):
""" Include the given rrule instance in the recurrence set exclusion
    list. Dates which are part of the given recurrence rules will not
    be generated, even if some inclusive rrule or rdate matches them.
"""
```

So, even if I add an RDATE, if it is exclude by a rule added by `exrule` it will not show up in my occurrences. Same goes for the `exdate` function, hence my working second example.